# Journey, tracking subscribers in WAIT state

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, query, journeybuilder, data-views

I have a question about Journeys, can I track subscribers that are in a state of WAIT inside a journey? 
I tried to track with Data View: Journey Activity but the  column JourneyActivityObjectID is not populated when the state is WAIT, so i cant track with some joins to Subscribers. I tried to use a REST API call that someone posted here some years ago to find the Journey History of all contacts but it doesnt work. There is any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all your journeys history through `interactions` undocumented REST API.

First of all, you need to get your journey's Definition ID via a GET call to:

```
/interaction/v1/interactions/?name=JOURNEY_NAME
```

The Definition ID is located inside a nested array called items.

Then, through a POST call to the endpoint below, you can get all you journeys history, including contacts in wait activities.

```
/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search
```

The payload should be something like:

```
{
    "definitionIds": [
        "06d6f3f6-4532-4fb3-908c-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "start": "2019-10-23T12:29:11.882Z",
    "end": null,
    "extras": "all"
}
```

You can add filters to get the history of the latest version for example,..

The response will contain what you need along with history of all interactions that occured inside of you journey:

```
{
            "id": "2157xxx",
            "mid": 50000xxxx,
            "eventId": "462f6eae-e39a-4c3f-8da4-d6eexxxx",
            "definitionId": "06d6f3f6-4532-4fb3-908c-49xxxx",
            "definitionName": "CARTESxxxx",
            "eventName": "CARTESxxxx",
            "contactKey": "0032X00002Kxxxx",
            "transactionTime": "2019-11-20T13:03:10.513Z",
            "status": "Waiting",
            "message": "",
            "activityId": "be4fd131-2cdf-4f75-873b-b1839xxxx",
            "activityType": "WaitActivity",
            "activityName": "1 minute"
        }
```

I invite you to read [this article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/) for a step by step guide.